# Merge this array in one

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge an array (KAWAA) to the `$messages` array , i tried with `$incidences[$counter]['messages']['toasty']`, but it adds only one message to the end, while I want every message to be added.

```
$messages = SellerIncidence::getMessages((int)$i['id_seller_incidence']);
$test =  array_merge($messages, array('KAWAA' => "lol"));
$incidences[$counter] = array_merge($incidences[$counter], array('messages' => $messages));
$incidences[$counter]['messages']['toasty'] = 1;
```

Comment: var_dump($test) should reflect the merge of $messages array and the array you have with KAWAA in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i understand your question, you want to add a message with the key `'KAWAA'` and the text `'lol'` to your messages. The easiest way to do this is:

```
// Check if the key already exists to prevent overwriting another message
if (!array_key_exists('KAWAA', $messages) {
    $messages['KAWAA'] = 'lol';
}
```

This also works for adding the field `'messages'` to the `$incidences` array:

```
if (!array_key_exists('messages', $incidences[$counter])) {
    $incidences[$counter]['messages'] = $messages;
} else {
    $incidences[$counter]['messages'] = array_merge($messages, $incidences[$counter]['messages']);
}
```

If you intend to add multiple messages, your `array_merge`solution is the way to go. Just make sure you know, that if both arrays have the an identical key, the latter array provided to `array_merge` will overwrite the value of the preceding one. In case the messages returned from `SellerIncidence::getMessages` are more important than the ones you add, you should flip the parameters:

```
$test = array_merge(['KAWAA' => 'lol'], $message);
```